# Chat Program wont write line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

i am trying to create a Basic lan chat program and its going pretty well, But i have one problem. I cant get my program to write on a new line! Whenever i hit button1 it should add your text to the chatlog, Cant figure out why this isnt working. Any help would be great!

Code:

```
Using Writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("\\NAS02\Justin\Rocketdrive\support\" & My.Settings.chat & ".txt")
        Writer.Write(RichTextBox1.Text)
        Writer.WriteLine(My.Settings.name & ":" & "" & TextBox1.Text)
    End Using
```

Comment: This can happen sometimes, try `writer.flush(); `
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did the above comment help?